# Is ん an abbreviation of の here?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, abbreviations

The [*Yomiuri*](https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/local/shiga/feature/CO055052/20220102-OYTAT50233/) had this sentence recently:

> こんだけ土【つち】のついた野菜【やさい】触【さわ】ったん、初【はじ】めてですわ
> *I've never touched a vegetable with so much dirt on it before.*

I have been told that ん can be an abbreviation of の, making the whole preceding part function like an extended noun phrase subject. If so, would a more grammatically analogous (though less natural-sounding) sentence be...

> *This is my first touching of a vegetable with so much dirt on it*

I have seen the ん hanging on to the ends of phrases such as the one above and was wondering whether I am understanding its function correctly.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but this particular use of ん is observed in certain dialects. In standard Japanese, の in that position is not reduced to ん.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39809/what-does-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%9f%e3%82%93-mean and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/78362/what-%e3%81%97%e3%82%82%e3%83%bc%e3%81%9f%e3%82%93-could-mean